# Gazebo skid steer drive and navigation stack

Tags: gazebo, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use gazebo skid steering drive plugin for my  4 wheelled robot and then use navigation stack like in ROS Tutorials.

The question is whould it work or I need something else for working?(maybe another controller)
Now I've created urdf of my robot with skid steering drive controller, I see that it publish to odom and tf, and it seems ground thuth, but I'm not shure about that because didn't find a lot of information.

- also I want to see a code of skid steering plugin, but I found only old version =(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158576/gazebo-skid-steer-drive-and-navigation-stack/) by [denzist](https://answers.ros.org/users/15161/denzist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've solved following this tutorial.
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo

---

Originally posted by [Dani C](https://answers.ros.org/users/12031/dani-c/) with karma: 126 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having similar problems. I am not really sure how this plug-in works and it only publish joint_states if you specify a namespace. I am using the ros_control package to for control.

---

Originally posted by [Dani C](https://answers.ros.org/users/12031/dani-c/) with karma: 126 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [denzist](https://answers.ros.org/users/15161/denzist/) on 2014-04-30**:
ok. Thanks